# Java streams Map to Dto in Map<String,List> by specific attribute in Java 8

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I want to get the list after using stream and then mapping person object to its dto.

I kept the "VALUE" as a enum like VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3.
Here is my values in `Map<String (id), List<Person>>`

```
Id, Tag, Value, Date , Message
p1, VALUE1, 10, 10-10-2000 , "Message"
p2, VALUE1, 20, 10-10-2000 , "Message"
p1, VALUE2, "Text", 10-10-2000 , "Message"
p2, VALUE2, "Text", 10-10-2000 , "Message"
p1, VALUE3, 11-11-2000, 10-10-2000 , "Message"
p2, VALUE3, 12-11-2000, 10-10-2000 , "Message"
```

What I want to get this result shown below.

```
Tag, Id, Value, Date
VALUE1, p1, 10, "10-10-2000"
VALUE1, p2, 20, "10-10-2000"  
VALUE2, p1, "Text", "10-10-2000"  
VALUE2, p2, "Text", "10-10-2000"  
VALUE3, p1, 11-11-2000, "10-10-2000"  
VALUE3, p2, 12-11-2000, "10-10-2000"
```

As you can see, Value column has different values (String, Int, Date). That's why I defined value as a object. I also store the date as a localdate.

Here is my Value class shown below.

```
public enum Value {
    VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3
}
```

Here is my Dto class shown below.

```
public class PersonDto {
    private Value value;
    private String id;
    private String date;
    private Object result;
}
```

How can I do that?

Here is my code snippets shown below. However, I cannot continue

```
static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

    List<PersonDto > result= persons.values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream).map(person->
                    String date = LocalDate.parse(person.getEventDate(), formatter) // Error
                    new PersonDto (person.getEvent(),person.getEmpID(),
                            ,person.getEvent())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());..
```

Comment: So, you want the same data, minus the message with the first two columns swapped?

Comment: @g00se I cannot map to object to dto as value is defined as an Object.

Comment: @g00se I edited my post after redefining the collection

Comment: `persons.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).map(p -> new PersonDto(...)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @英語は苦手 I revised my post. I followed your way but I cannot convert localdate to string.

Comment: You can't have two fields with identical name `value`- it would not compile. Why second value is type `Object`? What's the point of storing date as a string?

Comment: `String date = formatter.format(person.getEventDate())`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I fixed it. I shared the answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer shown below

```
List<PersonDto> yearlyFinancialReportDtos = persons.values().stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream).map(person ->
                        new YearlyFinancialReportDto(person.getValue(),person .getId(),formatter.format(person .getDate())
                                ,person .getResult()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```